# Plotting 3 cols of pandas dataframe as heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I'm almost certain that this is a duplicate, but I'm having trouble finding the answer in a reasonable amount of time.

I have dataframe with the three columns below:

```
    COLS  FUNCS  FLUFF
32     1      1    3.24707
33     1      2   14.89260
34     1      3   48.60840
35     1      4   73.68160
36     2      1    4.19922
37     2      2   64.89260
38     2      3   87.91500
39     2      4   91.01560
40     4      1   23.58400
41     4      2   87.89060
42     4      3   95.38570
43     4      4   98.33980
44     8      1   34.47270
45     8      2   95.43460
46     8      3   99.04790
47     8      4   99.80470
```

I want to plot a heat map of these data with COLS on the horizontal axis and FUNCS on the vertical axis with cells that are scaled according to FLUFF.  **I don't want to use seaborn**.  I want to use matplotlib and/or pandas exclusively.

If you also have some insight on how to achieve a logarithmic color scheme, that would also would great.

Comment: Is you matrix sparse? Why does the `COLS` column skip values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index(['COLS', 'FUNCS']).FLUFF.unstack(0).pipe(plt.imshow)
```

should do it for you.

As cel mentioned in the comments, if your data is actually sparse, you might want to do a `.reindex` to insert all the rows and columns, filling the NaNs appropriately.

For the log scale have a look at http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!